# How can HTML show content of <script> file?

Tags: html, text

I want to embed a lisp source file into the script tag in my html file. I am providing the file.lisp data as src to script (file.lisp is in the same folder as my html file):

```
<script src="./file.lisp"></script>
```

which doesn't show the content of my file.lisp. Is there any way of providing type="text/lisp" or something like this for html to show the content of the lisp file?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `embed` tag:

```
<embed src="file.lisp">
```

Comment: This doesn't work with absolute or relative paths to file.lisp. Also removing the path and only having "file.lisp" didn't show the content of it.

Comment: For a more complex solution you can use this syntax highlighter: [Prism](https://prismjs.com/)

Comment: `<embed src="./file.lisp" type="type/plain">` also didnt help

Comment: It should be `type="text/plain"` or `type="text/html"`.